# MSTest EventListener

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mstest, nunit-2.5

NUnit has special [event listener](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=eventListeners&r=2.5) to respond to events that occur in the course of a test run. Does MSTest have some similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

MSTest has attributes you can use to get similar functionality:

- [AssemblyInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx)
- [ClassInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx)
- [TestInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx)
- [TestCleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcleanupattribute.aspx)
- [ClassCleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classcleanupattribute.aspx)
- [AssemblyCleanup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblycleanupattribute.aspx)

One behavior that can catch people off guard is that the order in which these methods fire might not be what you expect.  Because tests are run in a non deterministic order you may get multiple class initializes before you get a class cleanup, so you can't rely solely on the class cleanup to isolate test cases across classes.  There is a good writeup of this behavior on [Mark Seemann's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/01/06/classcleanupmayrunlaterthanyouthink.aspx).